# matplotlib time series TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The data in my csv likes this:

```
staff_id    clock_time  device_id   latitude    longitude
1001    2020/9/20 7:26  d_1 24.48237852 118.1558955
1001    2020/9/20 5:30  d_1 24.59689407 118.0863806
1001    2020/9/18 4:17  d_2 24.59222786 118.0955275
1001    2020/9/16 3:33  d_2 24.59208312 118.0957197
1001    2020/9/15 8:34  d_2 24.59732974 118.0859644
1001    2020/9/14 4:43  d_2 25.68714724 119.3918519
1002    2020/9/13 1:17  d_3 24.58618235 118.1065715
1002    2020/9/11 9:20  d_3 24.63024186 118.0667598
1002    2020/9/10 7:22  d_3 24.48287497 118.1542957
1002    2020/9/7 5:38   d_4 25.07601853 118.7335211
1003    2020/9/5 5:44   d_6 24.59803941 118.0863071
1003    2020/9/4 7:37   d_6 24.48285023 118.1545752
1003    2020/9/3 2:38   d_6 24.6381382  118.0677933
1003    2020/8/31 6:43  d_7 24.49278011 118.1395677
1003    2020/8/30 11:41 d_7 24.59205252 118.0955596
1003    2020/8/29 3:35  d_7 24.51817637 118.1764342
1003    2020/8/28 5:05  d_7 24.59603175 118.0846872
1003    2020/8/27 2:55  d_8 26.39899424 117.7866387
1003    2020/8/26 7:45  d_8 26.39900029 117.7866379
1003    2020/8/26 3:09  d_8 26.40672436 117.8008659
1003    2020/8/26 0:26  d_8 26.89169118 117.1612365
1003    2020/8/25 9:38  d_8 26.89764297 117.1760012
1003    2020/5/19 8:29  d_8 24.47420087 118.1085551
1003    2020/5/18 9:06  d_8 24.473124   118.1705641
1003    2020/5/16 7:54  d_8 24.5101858  117.8954614
```

I use this code to split dataframe to sub-dataframes according to `staff_id` and `device_id`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  

df = pd.read_csv(r'for_test.csv', parse_dates=[1], encoding='utf-8')
gb = df.groupby(['staff_id','device_id'])
sub_dataframe_list = []
for i in gb.indices:
    sub_df = pd.DataFrame(gb.get_group(i))
    sub_dataframe_list.append(sub_df)

for sub_dataframe in sub_dataframe_list:
    x = sub_dataframe['clock_time'].values
    y = sub_dataframe['longitude'].values
    z = sub_dataframe['latitude'].values
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    plt.show()
```

I want to use matplotlib to output longitude and latitude in 3D space according to the time series
`clock_time`, but error message is:

```
To register the converters:
    >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
    >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 18, in <module>
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 2366, in scatter
    self.auto_scale_xyz(xs, ys, zs, had_data)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 498, in auto_scale_xyz
    np.column_stack([X, Y]), not had_data)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in column_stack
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 641, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It seems that clocktime its a 'string' type. Is it ? from the function 'scatter' x shoud be an array or a float, that's why you get the error because 'clocktime' seems to be a string.
Docs: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Comment: Why don't you convert `clocktime` to `datetime` with `df['clocktime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['clocktime'])`

Comment: @QuangHoang I modified my code `df['clock_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['clock_time'])`
but error message is:test1.py 18 <module>
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

axes3d.py 2366 scatter
self.auto_scale_xyz(xs, ys, zs, had_data)

axes3d.py 498 auto_scale_xyz
np.column_stack([X, Y]), not had_data)

shape_base.py 640 column_stack
return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1) TypeError:
invalid type promotion

Answer (score 0):

When you read your DataFrame, pass *parse_dates* parameter, to specify
which columns convert to *datetime*. Something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('for_test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1])
```

*sep* is not needed, as its default value is just a comma.

Then when you run *df.info()*, you should get something like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   staff_id    3 non-null      int64         
 1   clock_time  3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   device_id   3 non-null      object        
 3   latitude    3 non-null      float64       
 4   longitude   3 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

Note that *clock_time* column is now of *datetime64[ns]* type.

And as far as drawing is concerned, I came up with the following code,
generating subplots in 3 columns:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16), tight_layout=True)
dfCnt = len(sub_dataframe_list)
rowCnt = math.ceil(dfCnt / 3)
for idx, df in enumerate(sub_dataframe_list):
    row = df.iloc[0]
    x = df['clock_time']
    # Convert datetime to hours from minimal time
    x = (x - x.min()).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
    ax = fig.add_subplot(rowCnt, 3, idx + 1, projection='3d',
        title=f'{row.staff_id}, {row.device_id}')
    ax.title.set_position([.5, 0.96])
    ax.scatter(x, df['longitude'], df['latitude'])
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
plt.show()
```

Note that *fig* must be created **before** the loop.
In the loop you can add consecutive subplots.
After the loop there should be *plt.show()*.

To identify subplots, I added a title - grouping key from each group.

Comment: Thanks!Now my task is to use plt.show() to show each sub-dataframe, instead of displaying all sub-dataframe in one plt, how should this be done?Can you modify your code?I need to save each sub-dataframe, if they are put together, it will be confused.

Comment: Sorry, I never tried such combination like multiple figures. I only created a single figure, sometimes with multiple subplots.